# How can I create a search form with check boxes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

Lets say I have recipes and ingredients, so there is a relation n:m.

Ok, there is everything ok and the relationship works and I have a join table named ingredients_recipe and its store recipe id and ingredient id for each recipe in the database.

Now, I want to create a search form where you can select ingredients and then it show recipes with thoses ingredients.

For example:

I select potato, tomato and rice, so it should show recipes with thoses ingredients.

Comment: So what is your problem now?

Comment: Check out this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) as well as [this one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form). Post again when you have a *specific* programming issue. As it stands now, you're asking for a tutorial, which is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following view as well as search code:

View:

```
  <%= form_tag (search_url) do %>
    <% @ingredients.each do |ing| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "ingredient_ids[]", ing.id, id: => "ingredient_ids_#{ing.id}" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def search
  @recipes = Recipe.joins(:ingredients_recipes).where(
    ingredients_recipes: { ingredient_id: params[:ingredient_ids] } 
  )
end
```